# Category articles "read more" links not active

Tags: categories, read-more

If I click on a category in my Wordpress blog, it displays an excerpt of all articles in the category, and finishes with a word that says "continue" which has no hyperlink.

[Example here](http://www.superlogical.net/category/computing/windows/internet-explorer/).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the theme index.php (or other theme template file) and look for something like this:

```
<div id="more_reading">
    ...
</div>
```

replace with:

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
<div id="more_reading">
    ...
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or just remove "Continue"

Answer (score 0):

That 'Continue' you see is part of the next page/previous page functionality. If you look at the other pages of the site [http://www.superlogical.net/page/2/], when there are enough articles, it will display the continue with clickable arrows beside it.

You can see how to style the paging links here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links

Comment: OK.  I would of thought if there were no more articles to display there would be no need to display the word "continue", as there is nothing to continue to.  Zeo's fix worked above.